# Is it safe to add security features to a mass-distributable website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ssl, openid

I'm making a website that I'm planning on making readily deployable by users; they'll be able to take my source code and deploy it to their own server and run it as their own.

I was thinking of trying to incorporate SSL and OpenID and other features into the website. Would giving the users access to these files (such as my OpenID/Twitter/Facebook client key and secret, or the SSL certificate stuff, or whatever else..) be a potential security hazard or anything? Would they be able to do anything dangerous with this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL is not the app's concern

All client key and secret are your own responsibility... I wouldn't distribute them openly.

Normally what one does is to read this information from the environment

```
facebook_client_key = ENV["FACEBOOK_CLIENT_KEY"]
```

so the deployer has only to configure the environment, not the application.

Answer (score 0):

I would steer clear of adding things like your clients keys and secrets to any files you distribute to your users. They're called secrets for a reason! I don't known the ins and outs of Facebook or Twitter's APIs but certainly with products such as Akismet, the anti-spam addon for Wordpress, the key is used to identify your particular Wordpress instance.

If you are using a Wordpress site for commerical purposes, you're supposed to pay for Akismet. The problem is that whilst you might not be using it yourself for commerical purposes, depending on what you're making and distributing that's not to say that other people won't use it for commerical purposes, and end up ruining it not just for you, but for everyone else using your software.

You should make the keys and secrets part of your application's configuration and, perhaps, provide instructions on how your users can obtain their own.